# Show only number of letters from the text in laravel

Tags: php, css, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to show at my design only number of letters and the others will be like that  ...

How can i do that ?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Please could you give an example of what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is to use [`mb_strimwidth()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php) function:

```
{{ mb_strimwidth("Hello World", 0, 10, "...") }}
```

Comment: substr("$text", 0, 100) would be same ?

Comment: @SabaTandashvili for latin letters almost the same, but if you prefer to use `substr()` for some reason, use `mb_substr()`

Comment: Thanks for your help , but how can i use it in laravel which i have write that : {{mb_substr($allProduct->content, 0, 10, "...")}} 
and it back with error : mb_substr(): Unknown encoding &quot;...&quot;

Comment: It has been worked when i'm use this :{{mb_strimwidth($allProduct->content, 0, 10, "...")}}
Thank  you for your help